Intel real sense d455 is not working with ROS1 (Hardware Jetson Orin Nano)
While the Intel RealSense camera D455 is functioning correctly in the Intel RealSense viewer on the Jetson Orin Nano with ROS1 Noetic distribution on Ubuntu 20, the point cloud visualization through ROS1 with "roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch filters:=pointcloud" does not detect the camera.

This would seem to be the same as this question: Intel RealSense D455 is not working with ROS noetic in Jetson Orin Nano. Are you both working on the same course or class, or working on the project together?
